# formatted 3 columns adding up to 100%. But the last column is pushed down

Tags: css, xhtml

As stated from the title, this is my html code.

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="nav">
            <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="../media/images/Logo.png"
                             width="200px" height="200px" alt="Home" /></a>
            <ul class="navUL">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Movies</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Members</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>        
        </div>
        <div id="mainPage"></div>
        <div id="advertisement"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My CSS is -

```
body, #wrapper 
{
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#wrapper
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#nav
{
    background-image: url(../media/images/NavBackground.png);
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
}
#mainPage
{
    background-image: url(../media/images/ContentBackground.png);
    overflow: auto;
    width: 64%;
    height: 100%;
}
#advertisement
{
    background-image: url(../media/images/ContentBackground.png);
    float: right;
    width: 16%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The last column, the advertisement is pushed to the bottom. The total adds up to 100% so I don't know what is wrong.

I want to post the picture but I cant because low rep. Im sorry for the lack of picture.

Comment: If you include a link to the picture in the question, someone else will edit the question to move it into the question.

Comment: `#mainPage` is not floated, so it will always push `#advertisement` down. Try floating `#mainPage` or putting `#advertisement` before `#mainPage` in your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An item being pushed down is generally caused by floating elements. If you rearrange your HTML such that the advertisement is before your main page, it will fix your problem.

I have tested this with the following CSS:

```
body, #wrapper 
{
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#wrapper
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}

#nav
{
    background: red;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
}

#mainPage
{
    background: yellow;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 64%;
    height: 100%;
}

#advertisement
{
    background: blue;
    float: right;
    width: 16%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And the following HTML:

```
<div id="nav">

        <ul class="navUL">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Movies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Members</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

        </div>

        <div id="advertisement">test</div>
        <div id="mainPage">test</div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Changing the advertisement before the main page helped.

Answer (score 0):

See the following CSS

All divs inside wrapper have a left float and the total of the widths is 100%.

```
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}

#nav {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
}

#mainPage {
    float: left;
    width: 65%;
    height: 100%;
}

#advertisement {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
}
```